# kendo datepicker calendar missing today date

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler, kendo-datepicker, kendo-datetimepicker

I am using kendo scheduler and the the event template uses the kendo datepicker, unfortunately the kendo datepicker calendar is missing today's date which is 10th of december. Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: Maybe something to do with the style that is applied? Can you select the date even though you can't see it?

Answer (score 0):

check your kendo.bootstrap.css file. You must of over written this property:

.k-state-selected, .k-state-selected:link, .k-state-selected:visited, .k-list > .k-state-selected, .k-list > .k-state-highlight, .k-panel > .k-state-selected, .k-ghost-splitbar-vertical, .k-ghost-splitbar-horizontal, .k-draghandle.k-state-selected:hover, .k-scheduler .k-scheduler-toolbar .k-state-selected, .k-scheduler .k-today.k-state-selected, .k-marquee-color {

color: #fff;
    background-color: #428bca;
    border-color: #428bca

}

**UPDATE**

Ok i have done some further analysis, it seems like the css class thats attached to TodaysDate in the calendar is:

*.k-state-selected > .k-link, .k-panelbar > li > .k-state-selected, .k-panelbar > li.k-state-default > .k-link.k-state-selected {
    color: #fff;
}*

Have a look at your kendo.bootstrap.min.css to see if you have accidentally over-written it.

Comment: Ive just noticed something strange.. Why does your calendar go from 8th, 9th, 11th, 12th.. Wheres 10th? And why is it showing that 10th is on a Saturday instead of a Thursday.

Comment: yes, thats' the bug i am facing, no todays date on the calendar.